# A square dissection into squares of distinct size (aka "perfect squaring of a square")

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving

I am wondering if anyone can give an example of a square dissection into squares of distinct size. By using the distinctness we can see that the smallest square must be on the interior of the square, i.e. not touching any of the 4 sides of the original square. By scaling, we may assume that the given square is unit square; we may also assume that the unit square is in the usual position in the Euclidean plane. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square#Perfect_squared_squares) with two such dissections shown.

Comment: [Here](http://squaring.net/) is a useful resource.